# Change to unique layer name when Iterating over a set of layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, iteration

I am using the Clip algorithm with the 'Iterate over layers' option, which works great, but the output names are just 0 - 17, which isn't terribly helpful, as I don't know which shapefile is associated with with of the original clipping layers.  Is there anyway to include a unique name from the 'name' column in the Clipping layers attribute table?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Shapefiles, technically, have an 8.3 naming requirement. However they are implemented, spaces are not permitted, so that NAME column column not be used without mapping the spaces to underscores.

Comment: I've tried to solve this but couldnt. So my workaround is to rename the outputs afterwards using Python. Or replace the entire model with a python script, then it is easy to control the output layer names.